# Modify Objects on Insertion in ObjectModel or in ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

For a long time I wondered about the existence of the `ObjectModel`, and now I found the only good point is the attached property `ObjectModel.index`

However I'd like to maximize it's use, by using this information only once an `Object` is added to this `ObjectModel`.

If I create custom, reusable Components, I might add the following lines

```
import QtQml.Models 2.2
.....
ObjectModel.onIndexChanged: { ... set properties in dependance of the index ... }
```

to use the index information.
Now I am seeking for a less invasive solution, where I do not have to *prepare* a `Component` to be possibly used in an `ObjectModel`, but where I can do this `{ ... set properties in dependance of the index ... }` at the point in time, where I add the `Item` to the `ObjectModel` or once I use it in a `ListView` then.

What I am missing are some `signals`, such as `inserted(int index)` that I could handle, to set the properties. *This would also give me the opportunity to use other external properties, than the index*

Why? So I do not have to create Components as this:

```
RectangleThatCouldBeUsedInAObjectModelThatSetsWidthAndHeightAccordignly.qml:
Rectangle {
    ObjectModel.onIndexChanged: {
        width = Qt.binding(function() { return 100 * ObjectModel.index }
        height = Qt.binding(function() { return 100 * ObjectModel.index }
    }
}
```

but just use a `Rectangle` instead (*stupid example*)
An to ensure, that I do not have to import `QtQml.Models 2.2` in every Component, that might in maybe 10% of their usecases be used in an `ObjectModel`.

I just want to use it with minimal prior knowledge needed.

Comment: Is it for objects that are dynamically inserted to the model or for the objects marked up declaratively?

Comment: Ideally both. For the latter, I could use a wrapper-Item, and a `Component.onCompleted: {...}`-construct.

Comment: If you are only going to add items dynamically, then you can simply go for your own function that emits a custom signal after adding. In the other case I can't think of an easy solution. However, depending on what you do there might be a better way to do it. Your current example code doesn't make a lot of practical sense.

Comment: One practical use is, to have a flickable (`ListView`) to show a list of custom Buttons. Independently they shall work as normal Buttons (with a highly customized design), but once added to the `ListView` they should behave like a *Radiobutton*, having one marked as *pressed*. Those buttons might differ drastically from each other, so it is not sensible, to us a common delegate and a `ListModel` to generate them from. However I like you suggestion for the *dynamic way*, and will remember it, if no-one will come up with the ultimate solution.

Comment: What's good in your usecase about the `ObjectModel.index` attached property ?

Comment: The good thing about the attached property is, that I can use the `ObjectModel.onIndexChanged` as soon as I imported `QtQml.Models 2.2`, and it won't raise errors if it is not used inside a ObjectModel, but is triggered, as soon as it is added to one.

Comment: It's just that I don't see where you would need to depend on an index in an `ObjectModel`. Even if that was the case I'd define the binding in the same context as the `ObjectModel` definition, not in another file.

Comment: That is the whole point what I try to achive: To define the binding in the same context as the ObjectModel definition. But I can't find a way to it. So far this is the only tweak I found, to achive this binding, without having the file to depend on being in an `ObjectModel`. I will think about, how to rework the question, to make that point more clear.

Comment: You could use an adapter object, and put that between the model and actual item, delegating the model related functionality as its responsibility.

Comment: Can you show us the file where you define and use your `ObjectModel` ?

Comment: By now, I am unsure if what I try is achievable by the means of an `ObjectModel`, as I guess, that @ddrivers hints will help me to achive my goal without relying on that. I will rework the question as soon as I find the time.

Comment: Are you aware that you have access to the index anywhere in `ListView`s delegate not matter what the model is? If you want width/height or any other property depend on the index, that would just be like `height: 100 * model.index`

Comment: @KevinKrammer: Yes, but if I use an ObjectModel, I can - *afaik* - not modify any delegates, as the `delegate`-property of the `ListView` will be ignored. I could however use the `ObjectModel.count` as model, create my `delegate`, and assign the `ObjectModel.get(index)` as the child. Then I can use the delegate's `Component.onCompleted` to modify the properties of the ObjectModel's object.

Comment: @derM So you have different types of items in your `ObjectModel`? I mean, what is your reason for using it?

Comment: Aye. I have for example a couple of `Rectangles` in my ObjectModel, so they have some common attributes, I can access, but their children differ that much, that it is not feasible to use a `ListModel` and a `ListView` to generate them.